# Register variable holding list filtering instead of set_fact

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

`filtered` fact in the code below contains the filtered string and can be used throughout the playbooks during the execution:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
         filtered: " {{ some_arg }} | regex_search(...)"
```

However,  `filtered` is needed only inside the playbook. How to register the variable containing the same `filtered` result to avoid unnecessary fact creation...

Comment: set_fact does not create a fact, it actually sets the associated variable where it is invoked. If this task is only called once and "filtered" is different for each host, where is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well values you create with `set_fact` don't really get stored any where by default, they just exist in memory for the life of the playbook run. So you really shouldn't have to do anything.

Ignoring that point, I can mention that it is certainly possible to define variables at the play level,  block level, or task level.  In many cases you can use these to define variables without having to a 'task' just for defining the value.

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    play_filtered: "a play variable"
  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: play_filtered
  - debug:
      var: task_filtered
    vars:
      task_filtered: " a task variable"
  - vars:
      block_filtered: "a block variable"
    block:
    - debug:
        var: block_filtered


# PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************

# TASK [debug] *************************************************************************
# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "play_filtered": "a play variable"
# }

# TASK [debug] *************************************************************************
# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "task_filtered": " a task variable"
# }

# TASK [debug] *************************************************************************
# ok: [localhost] => {
#     "block_filtered": "a block variable"
# }
```

Ref: [Playbook keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html)